# How to know what button being pressed with a procedural style in C++ SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm coding a minesweeper game, and in the game, there are 2 types of buttons: the cells of the board and the utility buttons like restart and save game.

I coded the game in a procedural programming style, I wanna know how do I check which kind of button is pressed and thereby trigger different actions for those buttons elegantly. Because since we only have the mouse X and Y coordinates every frame from the mouse event, the way I tended to do it is to check whether a button has the mouse cursor in it or not when the mouse is being pressed. But this way of doing it is very clumsy and it starts getting more and more tedious when I have to do it for each of the scenes in the game (maybe the menu scene where you have only the utility buttons, or the game scene where you have both types of buttons).

I know you can use OOP and check every type of "clickable" object in every scene but I have already coded the game in the console with procedural programming style beforehand and I don't wanna waste time changing it into OOP style.

Comment: ***check every type of "clickable" object in every scene*** well, you can define a property yourself and associate it with each button. Assuming a button is a `struct` with different values like color, label, etc. you just need to add one more member for whether it is clickable. Or you can just search SFML docs if they already have some property like that.

Comment: BTW this seems to be a very broad question and probably it will attract opinionated answers, you may add some code (a [mre]) to be more specific and avoid opinionated answers.

Comment: If your buttons are objects themselves, the elegant way could be to iterate through all of them, checking if the mouse coordinates are contained inside. If so, then do the proper action (each button should be responsible of that)